# Unit testing nuxt fetch hook

Tags: jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to unit test with Nuxt. Everything's going smoothly, but my problem lies with unit testing fetch. It seems that since this.$axios isn't a library (well, it is, but is injected to the context), there's no easy way to jest.mock it. I've the few posts that there are on this, but they have not worked.

```
async fetch() {
    try {
        this.maxSpace = await this.$axios.$get('/api/system/max-space')
    }
    catch (err) {
        this.maxSpace = 0
    }
},
```

This is the simple code I'm attempting to unit test

Comment: What are those posts? What did you tried so far?

Comment: @kissu I've attempted to use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63638214/how-to-test-nuxt-js-asyncdata-and-fetch-hooks & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65165605/how-to-test-nuxt-with-jest . They have some information in them, but neither has seemed to work correctly for me.